# "Detaching" a subsite from the template used to create it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, sub-site, template

I previously created a custom subsite template and used it to create a couple of subsites. Now I have a request to add to the template, but I am unable to deactivate the template so that I can update the solution.

If I try to deactivate the solution so that I can update the file an error stating I don't have permission to deactivate appears. I am able to deactivate/activate new templates that haven't been used yet, however.

Is there a way to edit the template/ detach the subsites created with it so they are no longer dependent on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s the permission of the account who want to deactivate the solution?

The site Owner can only deactivate or delete the Site Template that already not used. The Site Collection Administrator can deactivate or delete a Site Template that already used or not.

Make sure you should be a Site Collection Administrator to deactivate the site template.

Check the article [Site Owner vs Site Collection Administrator](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/site-owner-vs-site-collection-administrator)

Comment: This does seem to have been the issue, as I am a Site Owner, not SCA. Is there a way to find out which users are Site Collections Admins (as someone that is not a SCA)?

Comment: You can go to site settings->click Go to top level site settings->Users and permissions->site collection administrators. Or go to SharePoint Admin Center->site collections->select the relevant site collection which includes the sub sites-> Owners->Manage Administrators.